# 7.- Number theory problem.

Tags: number-theory

Each of the numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ is 1 or $−1$, and we have
\begin{equation}
S = a_1 a_2  a_3  a_4 + a_2  a_3  a_4  a_5 + \cdots + a_n  a_1  a_2  a_3 = 0.
\end{equation}
Prove that $4 \mid n$.

Comment: I think there are missing details on the question. What would be the before-last sum term?

Comment: The terms are all the possible combinations.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

The sum consists of $n$ terms, each is $\pm1$.

If you replace $a_i$ by $-a_i$, the sum in the LHS changes by a multiple of $4$. By doing this several times, you can achieve that all $a_i=1$. If all $a_i=1$ then the LHS is $n$. The original sum ($0$) is a multiple of $4$, so $n$ is a multiple of $4$.